# PC is limited to 1 USB to IEEE-1284 Parallel Printer cable

Tags: usb, printer

I have two old printers with IEEE 1284 B ports.  I am using a USB to IEEE-1284 Parallel Printer cable for each; however, I can only get the PC to recognize one printer.  Both printers and cables test ok.  It appears the PC is limited to 1 USB to IEEE-1284 Parallel Printer cable.  Is there a way to get the PC to regognize 2 IEEE-1284 Parallel Printers?

Answer (score 2):

Check the serial numbers and other USB identifiers from the cable; if they're the same then the driver may not be able to tell the two apart.

Comment: Windows uses the serial numbers to 'tag' each device.  Many (cheaper) vendors put a static serial number in place instead of unique values.  Obtaining another brand usb-1284 cable should help.  (Should)